# Problem initializing a struct with the {0} initializer

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I encountered a bizarre problem while trying to use the {0} initializer on a struct.
The struct I built consists of a 2D array of size 4x4 and was defined as the following:

```
typedef struct Matrix{
double array[4][4];
} mat;
```

when I tried to initialize the struct with zero's using the following :

```
mat MAT_A = {0};
```

it only initialized part of the struct with zero's, but when I did something like this :

```
mat MAT_A = {0},MAT_B = {0};
```

then when I checked the content of MAT_A it was initialized to zero completely, though MAT_B was partly initialized like what was happened at the beginning when I only wrote :

`mat MAT_A = {0};`

I have no clue why it is happening and I will appreciate any insights.

```
int main(){
    int i,row = 0;
    mat MAT_A = {0}, MAT_B = {0};
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if(i%4 == 0)
            row++;
    
        printf("%f,", *(*(MAT_A.array + row) + i%4));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `it only initialized part of the struct with zero's` How do you know?

Comment: Because I've printed it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre], i.e. include the code that prints the data showing the problem.

Comment: Instead of doing "clever" stuff,  try [the idiomatic approach](https://godbolt.org/z/KTro9hMdx) - or  [if you want one loop](https://godbolt.org/z/oW51zYehT)

Comment: `printf("%f,", MAT_A.array[i / 4][i % 4]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not printing the result correctly:

```
printf("%f,", *(*(MAT_A.array + row) + i));
```

The value of `i` ranges from 0 to 15, and you're using that value to index the second dimension of the array.  That dimension only has size 4 so you're reading past the end of the array.  Doing so triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead of using `i` here, use `i%4`.  That will keep the second dimension index in the proper range.

Comment: I am aware of this and I tried to fix it before you edited my post.
It still does the same problem

Comment: Anyway I guess it is just the printing part, Thanks :)